# Solve the following inequality....

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Can you please verify if I've done this exercise correctly, and if you have a better solution, please, show it to me. Thank you!   (The exercise is in the left top corner.)

[image]

Comment: I stricly suggest you visit this page: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ...

Comment: too painful to read, please put effort if you really want an answer

Comment: It's not ok, http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ej27dk8llgl (click on full result)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, sketch the two functions and solve the inequality geometrically. It will save you from a lot of pain.